# for loop exit before callback is finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, bluebird

I have a for loop which is calling an async function. I need this function to then call a callback at the end of the for loop but only when all my async functions have returned their result. I have tried this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < vaccinsCount; i++){
    getVaccinAddress(i, address, provider, function(result){
       if(result.success){
         console.log("result:" + result.values);
         vaccines.push(result.values);
       } else {
         callback({success: false, message: result.message}); 
       }
   });
}
callback({success: true, values: vaccines});
```

instead what is happening is that the code enters the for loop then call then async function then exits straigh away. How could i get around this ?

getVaccinAddress is the Async Function that does a server call.

**EDIT**

I am using NodeJS, therefore the solution is to then use bluebird, I however have no idea on how to implement this with bluebird.

Comment: search SO and google for loop async

Comment: I have and I still don't understand how could I make it work.

Comment: your code in incomplete, what's in the getVaccinAddress function?

Comment: it is the async function.

Comment: What should occur if an error is thrown by `getVaccinAddress()` or if `result.success` is not `true`?

Comment: _"I am using NodeJS, therefore the solution is to then use bluebird, I however have no idea on how to implement this with bluebird."_ ? What do you mean by "therefefore" ? There was no mention of `Promise` requirement as part of solution at original Question. `Promise` usage is not a necessity for handling asynchronous processes.

Comment: @guest271314 what would be the solution if promises are not necessary.

Comment: @Rémi The approach at Answer should return expected result of calling `callback` once `vaccines.length === vaccinsCount` evaluates to `true`. What is expected result if an error is encountered; or `result.success` does not evaluate to `true`?

Comment: yes result.success is false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `callback()` when `vaccines.length` is equal to `vaccinsCount`

```
for(var i = 0; i < vaccinsCount; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    getVaccinAddress(i, address, provider, function(result) {
       if(result.success) {
         console.log("result:" + result.values);
         vaccines.push(result.values);
         if (vaccines.length === vaccinsCount) {
            // call `callback()` here
         }            
       }
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the code never gets into the if(vaccines.lenght === vaccinesCOunt)

Comment: @Rémi _"I have tried this but the code never gets into the if(vaccines.lenght === vaccinesCOunt)"_ That is why asked what expected result is if error occurs or `result.success` does not evaluate to `true`, which could be one reason why `vaccines.length === vaccinsCount` would not evaluate to `true`. You could alternatively call `callback` if `i` is equal to `vaccinsCount`, irrespective if `result.success` evaluates to `true`. Are any errors logged? Is `result.success` `true` for all calls to `getVaccinAddress`?

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using promises in this case.
It's a good way to manage your asynchronous calls:
https://davidwalsh.name/promises

If you are using promises your code would look something like this:

```
var promises = []
for(var i = 0; i < vaccinsCount; i++){
    promises.push(getVaccinAddress(i, address, provider));
    // getVaccinAddress will need to return a promise
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(result) {
   console.log('success');
})
.catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I though about using promis but I am coding in NodeJS i'm therefore unsure on how to make this work.

Comment: @Rémi use Bluebirdjs

Comment: If you are using NodeJS then even better. Install bluebird, its much faster than standard promises: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Ok i'll use bleubird it seems easier, but i still have no idea on how to implement this in bleubird.

Comment: What is the difference between using `Promise` and performing action when `vaccines.length === vaccinsCount`?